# 8 table join and selecting count(distinct()) not returning properly

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Tables:

```
User
UserId

UserRelation
UserRelationId | ManagerUserId (fk to User.UserId) | UserId

UserBusinessRelation
UserBusinessSaleId | BusinessId | UserId

Business
BusinessId

CampaignGroup
CampaignGroupId | BusinessId

Campaign
CampaignId | CampaignGroupId

Adgroup
AdgroupId | CampaignId

AdgroupKeyword
AdgroupKeywordId | AdgroupId

Click
ClickId | AdgroupKeywordId | Time (Unix Time, Double, Unsigned)

ClickAction
ClickActionId | ClickId | Time (unix time Double, Unsigned)
```

The first column in each of these is a PrimaryKey, Auto-Increment

Question: How do I go about joining these in the most efficient way possible, fully knowing that there could easily be a hundred thousand clicks per business and hundreds of businesses?

Here's my query:

`select count(distinct(ca.ClickActionId)), count(distinct(cl.ClickId)) from ClickAction ca 
inner join Click cl on cl.ClickId=ca.ClickId 
inner join AdgroupKeyword ak on ak.AdgroupKeywordId=cl.AdgroupKeywordId 
inner join Adgroup a on a.AdgroupId=ak.AdgroupId 
inner join Campaign c on c.CampaignId=a.CampaignId 
inner join CampaignGroup cg on cg.CampaignGroupId=c.CampaignGroupId 
inner join Business b on b.BusinessId=cg.BusinessId 
inner join UserBusinessSale ubs on ubs.BusinessId=b.BusinessId 
inner join UserRelation ur on ur.UserId=ubs.UserId 
where ur.ManagerUserId=3`

The problem with this is that I get back: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [count(distinct(ca.ClickActionId))] => 38290 [count(distinct(cl.ClickId))] => 38290 ) )`... which I absolutely know is not correct because there are many more clicks than clickActions (probably 10x more at a minimum)

Comment: Guessing but given what you are saying you need to outer join to clickaction, inner join will chop out all clicks with no click action. As for making this efficient, this is probably as good as it gets, unless you demormalise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, something seems wrong with the relationships - is Business REALLY necessary?
It looks like you are joining UserBusinessRelation and CampaignGroup by two of their foreign-keys.
Isolate the counts - run the SQL twice, once with each count statement, and see if you get anything different.

Also, I agree with Tony Hopkinson - if you are trying to count clicksActions that have not yet had a click, then you'll need that outer join.  On second look, you may have your click/clickAction relationship backward.. A clickAction is dependent on the existence of a click.

If, independently, the count(distinct column) works, you may be best to run two queries one after the other, or even within a transaction, as mySql will already have cached the indexes of the tables needed for counting.

Comment: Yes, Business is necessary because it holds much more information pertaining to the business itself rather than the campaignGroup as a whole... but I do see that I can eliminate that from the query.  Per Tony's suggestion, I've redone the query so that it first uses the Click table -> left join ClickAction -> inner join AdgroupKeyword to Click, etc..  And that seems to work.  I've also come to realize that I can just search for clicks / clickActions for a given day and then cache that particular day's results while also implementing an increment key for today's clicks/actions.